# How to identify recurring patterns in time-series data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, time-series

I am calculating ENSO indices using Matlab and one condition is that I have to find anomalous sea surface temperatures. The condition is that an El Niño event is characterised by sea surface temperatures that are 0.5 degrees above the normalised "0-value" for 5 months. I have gotten as far as to make my monthly time series data logical (i.e. "1" is a monthly data value above 0.5 and "0" is a monthly data value below 0.5), but I wanted to know if there was a command in Matlab that allows me to identify when this value repeats 5 times or more.

As an example code:

```
Monthly_data=[0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 0]
```

I would ideally need a command that finds when a minimum of five "1"s occur after each other. Does this exist?

If more info is needed please let me know, I am new to matlab so I am not yet sure of the structure and syntax that is valued for asking questions on here.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure this is what you need but perhaps gives you some direction.

```
> x = diff(Monthly_data);
> find(x==-1)-find(x==1)
ans =

   5   2   1   7
```

these are the lengths of the `1` sequences.  You may need to pad front and end of the array with `0` to eliminate sequences missing one boundary.

To find the start index of the sequence longer than 5:

```
> s=find(x==1);
> s(find(x==-1)-s>5)
ans =  18
```

or

```
> s(find(x==-1)-s>=5)
ans =

    2   18
```

note that because of the diff lag, these are one more than the array index, or consider it as position for zero based indexing.

Comment: This is super helpful! Thank you for your guidance and advice!